# CNAME to S3 returns the S3 URL

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, cname-record, namecheap

I've setup a static website on S3 under a `www.mydomain.com` bucket. I also created a CNAME record for it in Namecheap looking like this:

- Type: CNAME Record
- Host: `www`
- Value: `www.mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast1.amazonaws.com`

It redirects correctly when I go to `www.mydomain.com` but the URL being displayed is of S3 and not my domain. If it helps, here's some output from `dig`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.mydomain.com.    1177    IN      CNAME   www.mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.
www.mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com. 60 IN CNAME s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.
s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com. 5 IN A 54.231.242.137
```

When I checked the headers from `curl`, I got a 301.

Comment: It would probably help if you stopped censoring your domain name and S3 URLs.

Comment: Doc say: _When you create a bucket, in any region, Amazon S3 updates DNS to reroute the request to the correct location, which might take time. In the meantime, the default rule applies and your virtual hosted–style request goes to the US East (N. Virginia) region, and Amazon S3 redirects it with HTTP 307 redirect to the correct region._

Comment: @FedericoSierra that doesn't apply when the region-specific website or REST endpoints are used.  It only applies to requests sent to hostnames in the format `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: @Conrad you're definitely going to need to fill us in on your bucket name, as has already been mentioned.  This is not the expected behavior, so it's essentially impossible for us to guess what you might have misconfigured or omitted from your question (such as whether you actually created 2 buckets, one without the www, which isn't going to work with namecheap).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - in have two buckets in S3 - `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`. `mydomain.com` is where the site is, and I set `www.mydomain.com` to redirect to `mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast1.amazonaws.com`... I moved the files to `www.mydomain.com` and removed the redirect.

Answer (score -3):

Instead using a CNAME you can set an A record pointing directly to the HOST_IP_ADDRESS:

```
Type: A Record
Host: www.mydomain.com
Value: 54.231.242.137
```

Comment: Which is impossible with S3, as S3 doesn't have single or fixed IPs. S3 has millions of potential IPs, more than one at once, and they change regularly.

Comment: Then, in order to avoid 301, the CNAME ServerName should be declared into webserver vhost config. Supposing apache: _ServerName www.mydomain.com.s3-website-ap-southeast1.amazonaws.com_

Comment: Again impossible, as S3 is under Amazon's control, not yours. It's a hosted static file service.